# Where should an oil sensor go in on a straight 6?

Tags: chevrolet, sensor, gauges, c10

Recently sourced VHX Dakota Digital gauges for an 84 c10 that has a straight 6. Found how the speed sensor should go in, the water temp sensor is attached to the inlet replacing what’s there but I’m not finding where the oil sensor is on either side of the straight 6. Tried Dakota support and the manual only covers a v8 or LS motor swap. Currently, this has idiot gauges so I’d imagine there’s a sensor somewhere. Didn’t find anything for my motor in the book I bought (Chilton and Hayes).

Where should the oil sensor go on a straight 6?

Comment: Which straight 6 engine? There answer will depend on the actual engine. Please edit and add more details on the make and model, as well as other information that is relevant, like is it the original engine or a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

The oil sensor position for the I6 should be above the starter on the right side of the engine (right side as you sit in the driver's seat) just below the lifter galley cover. It is almost in line with the dipstick tube.

[image]

Comment: Ok, that might be what's throwing me off because there is nothing there but a bolt. Will have a definite this evening with a pic.

Comment: It may also be at the back of the block just above the bell housing and behind the head. Check there as well. A lot harder to see. I saw it listed there, but I was assuming you had the more normal placement. If there is a bolt or a plug at the position in the picture, it can be used for the sender without issue. Just remove the plug (if you can ... they like to seize!)

Comment: ok, good to know. First time playing with the straight 6, also still looking for the alternator. I've ordered three sources for schematic references and the only reason I've been messing with the gauges is because the speedo needle is broken so swapping out the gauge and cable this weekend.

Comment: Also, unless the Dakota Digital stuff is replacing the idiot light (in the physical hole in the dash), it wouldn't be a bad idea to keep it. A light is a lot easier to get your notice then a gauge will aver be.

Comment: Alternator? Hanging right off the front of the engine? Should be attached to the belt and are very much the same looking thing like most V8s and the like. GM's alternators are all pretty much the same.

Comment: Will go to chat and ping you